# Storing array as a key pair in a json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

There are three arrays ,

```
var names = ["Increment","Decrement"]
var values1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
var values2 = [7,8,9,10,11]
```

Now i would like to construct a json like

```
{"names":[
    {"Increment":"1,2,3,4,5,6"},
    {"Decrement":"7,8,9,10,11"}
]}
```

Comment: what is the data type of increment? and why do you want to get an array with objects instead of an object with properties?

Comment: @Sarath, why the edit of the wanted result?

Comment: @nina yes..the user2860954 denotes explanation and un-formated array.. as his result and asking for json..

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty object and change it's properties.

```
var names = ["Increment","Decrement"];
var values1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var values2 = [7,8,9,10,11];

var json = [{}];

 json[0].Increment = values1.toString();
 json[0].Decrement = values2.toString();

console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like this:

```
var names = ["Increment","Decrement"];
var values1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var values2 = [7,8,9,10,11];

var yourArray = [];

for ( var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    o = {};
    o[names[i]] = windows['values'+ i].join(',');
    yourArray.push(o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change the data structure to a more compact style.

```
var names = ["Increment", "Decrement"],
    values1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    values2 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    obj = {};

obj[names[0]] = values1;
obj[names[1]] = values2;
```

Result:

```
{
    Increment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    Decrement: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
}
```

To generate a JSON, you may convert it with `JSON.stringify()` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = {'names' : names.map(function(val, ind) { var elem = {}; elem[val] = this['values' +   ++ind].toString(); return elem; }) };
```